# how to build a Comma seperated list from a table in SQL CE?

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

how to build a Comma seperated list from a table in SQL CE ?

I have table named Group  and it has two columns ID and Name

I want to select a one comma seperated string from Group table.

So IF I have 3 records as follows in group table

```
ID  | Name 
 1  | Msh
 2  | Nsh
 3  | Lsh
```

I want to get a one comma seperated list of all three names like this `Msh,Nsh,Lsh`

How can I get this done is `SQL CE` ?

Comment: Best build that in your logic and not in SQL

Comment: But , I need to use it in a Querry

Comment: Use can use my SQLCECMD tool

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
DECLARE @COMMA VARCHAR(MAX)
 SET @COMMA =''
 SELECT @COMMA =@COMMA +name+',' FROM yourtablename
 SELECT SUBSTRING(@COMMA,0,LEN(@COMMA))
```

Comment: variable Declaration is not supported in SQL CE ,  This method will not work with SQL CE

Answer (score 0):

```
    You can develop a simple logic in SQL. This is a dummy code you can try and modify the code as per your requirements.

    declare
        i varchar2(100);
        j varchar2(100);
        begin
        for i in (select name from avrajit)
        loop
        j:=i.name||','||j;
        end loop;
        dbms_output.put_line(j);
        end;

---------------------------------------
OUTPUT
---------------------------------------

Hitesh,Sushil2,Mukul,Shyam,Nikheel,Avrajit,Sushil,

Statement processed.
```

Comment: Variable declaration is not supported in SQL CE, So this method will not work with SQL CE. Unfortunately this is not answering my qustion.